# How do you select an item when I have created a drop down menu on Dreamweaver?

Tags: html, css, web, drop-down-menu, dreamweaver

I've created a web page and I am currently creating a contact form. I've added a drop down menu however, when I click on one of the buttons in the drop down menu, it doesn't select it.

If anyone could help me it would be great.

Thanks :)

Comment: Please post some minimal identifiable code.

Comment: im trying but it doesnt do a line at a time it all joins up, do you know how i can fix that?